# Import JSON array in CouchBase

Tags: json, couchbase

I want to use CouchBase to store lots of data. I have that data in the form:

```
[
  {
    "foo": "bar1"
  },
  {
    "foo": "bar2"
  },
  {
    "foo": "bar3"
  }
]
```

I have that in a `json` file that I zipped into `data.zip`. I then call:

```
cbdocloader.exe -u Administrator -p **** -b mybucket C:\data.zip
```

However, this creates a single item in my bucket; not three as I expected. This actually makes sense as I should be able to store arrays and I did not "tell" CouchBase to expect multiple items instead of one.

The temporary solution I have is to split every items in multiple`json` files, then add the lot of them in a single `zip` file and call `cbdocloader` again. The problem is that I might have lots of these entries and creating all the files might take too long. Also, I saw in the doc that `cbdocloader` uses the filename as a key. That might be problematic in my case...

I obviously missed a step somewhere but couldn't find what in the documentation. How should I format my `json` file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You haven't missed any steps. The cbdocloader script is very limited at the moment. Couchbase will be adding a cbimport and cbexport tool in the near future that will allow you to add json files with various formats (including the one you mentioned). In the meantime you will need to use the current workaround you are using to get your data loaded.